# How to append <form:input path="" /> into table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to add row if user press button add.

I using jsp and jquery `.append()`, but it's doesnt work

I tired to try this append for `<form:input path="">` into table.

HTML code

```
<table class="table" id="fileMappingTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><fmt:message key='fileMapping.parameter.sequence' /></th>
            <th style="text-align:right;" colspan=2><a href="#" id="addSequence" class="button tiny" style="margin: 0;">Add sequence</a></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <form:input path="sequence" id="sequence"
                    cssClass="validate[required]"
                    cssErrorClass="error validate[required]" />
                <form:errors path="sequence" cssClass="error" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:radiobutton path="value" id="default" value=""/><label for="default">Default</label> <br>

                <form:radiobutton path="value" id="startCharacter" value=""/><label for="startCharacter">Start character</label>
                <form:input path="firstCharacterPosition" id="firstCharacterPosition"
                    cssClass="validate[required]"
                    cssErrorClass="error validate[required]"/>
                <label for="length">Length</label>
                <form:input path="length" id="length"
                    cssClass="validate[required]"
                    cssErrorClass="error validate[required]"/><br>

                <form:radiobutton path="value" id="dateTime" value=""/><label for="dateTime">Date & Time</label>
                <form:select path="">
                    <form:option value="">DATE</form:option>
                    <form:option value="">DATE AND TIME</form:option>
                </form:select><br>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: top;">
                <a href="#">remove</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript code

```
$("#addSequence").click(function(){
    $("#fileMappingTable:last").append(
        "<tr>" +
            "<td style='vertical-align: top;'>" +
                "<form:\input path='sequence' id='sequence' cssClass='validate' cssErrorClass='error validate' />" +
                "<form:\errors path='sequence' cssClass='error' />" +
            "</td>" +
            "<td>" +
                "<form:radiobutton path='value' id='default' value=''/><label for='default'>Default</label><br>" +
                "<form:radiobutton path='value' id='startCharacter' value=''/><label for='startCharacter'>Start character</label>" +
                "<form:input path='firstCharacterPosition' id='firstCharacterPosition' cssClass='validate[required]' cssErrorClass='error validate[required]'/>" +
                "<label for='length'>Length</label>" +
                "<form:input path='length' id='length' cssClass='validate[required]' cssErrorClass='error validate[required]'/><br>" +
                "<form:radiobutton path='value' id='dateTime' value=''/><label for='dateTime'>Date & Time</label>" +
                "<form:select path=''>" +
                    "<form:option value=''>DATE</form:option>" +
                    "<form:option value=''>DATE AND TIME</form:option>" +
                "</form:select><br>" +
            "</td>" +
            "<td style='vertical-align: top;'>" +
                "<a href='#'>remove</a>" +
            "</td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );
});
```

if i click the button with `id="addSequence"` it will be add row with `<form:input path=""/>` like on javascript code

thanks before

Comment: please share you html too. Like `fileMappingTable, addSequence` elements

Comment: Are you trying to write jsp/java form input from javascript code ???

Comment: @vikrantsingh yes i tried to write jsp form input into table row with javascript code

Comment: `form:input` is the server side

Comment: @jogesh_pi the html code now available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSTL or your Spring MVC form tag will execute first and create the normal tag or html. Then after that you will manipulate the html using Jquery, not the other way around. Create first spring tags before manipulate it with jquery